# How to make sure relative URL works when site is not on root domain?

Tags: php, theme-development, functions, themes, array

I just tried installing my theme on another WP install that lies in a subdirectory of the domain. I never really thought too hard about subdirectories, but it does happen so I know I need to change it. Absolute URLS aren't feasible since I plan on distributing the theme.

The catch here is that the URL needs to work inside of an array more specifically with some themes settings. Here is how they look.

```
function mytheme_get_theme_mods() {
    $defaults = array(
        'mytheme_header_logo'  => '/wp-content/themes/mytheme/img/logo.png',
        'mytheme_footer_logo'  => '/wp-content/themes/mytheme/img/footerlogo.png',
        'mytheme_middle_image' => '/wp-content/themes/mytheme/img/middleimg.png'
    );
    return $defaults;
}
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: "Absolute URLS aren't feasible since I plan on distributing the theme." -- this is false. If you use the appropriate Core functions to locate your files there will be no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of the functions wordpress offers to determine paths and URLs - see [Determining Plugin and Content Directories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories). For example use:

- [get_template_directory](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory) to

  > Retrieves the absolute path to the directory of the current theme, without the trailing slash.
- or [get_stylesheet_directory](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory) to

  > Retrieve stylesheet directory Path for the current theme/child theme.

You find more information on the linked codex page about determining directories.

---

**Edit:** In response to the comment.

This is how I'd do it:

```
function mytheme_get_theme_mods() {
    $tpl_dir_pth = get_template_directory();
    $defaults = array(
        'mytheme_header_logo' => $tpl_dir_pth . '/img/logo.png',
        'mytheme_footer_logo' => $tpl_dir_pth . '/img/footerlogo.png',
        'mytheme_middle_image' => $tpl_dir_pth . '/img/middleimg.png'
    );

    return $defaults;
}
```

Of course I don't know if the absolute path actually is what you want.

Comment: get_template_directory was the first approach I tried. Although it doesn't work when in the array value. Or atleast the ways I tried it.

Comment: Using get_template_directory seems to give me my ftp folders before the domain aswell. Not sure why as I don't have any rewrite functions. I tried get_template_directory_uri and it ended up working. I have to admit, my previous attempt I added the code between ' '. Thanks.